# Hide ribbon buttons

Tags: ribbon, custom-masterpage

I have a custom masterpage. How can I hide some buttons in the ribbon like:

**Open in explorer**

[image]

and **send file**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hided these buttons as follow. I created a feature and an elements.xml. Inside this elements.xml I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="RemoveRibbonButton" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>

  <CustomAction Id="RemoveRibbonButton" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer" />
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>

</Elements>
```

Answer (score 3):

EASY solution is the CSS. Just inspect element from browser and apply some css like

```
display: none;
```

[image]

If you need this across the site, then add these style into your master page. If you need this for a specific library only, then add these into that specific page using Content Editor Web Part. You can use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) plugin in Chrome for generating css.

Answer (score 0):

An an example this selector works for selcting open with explorer. you can use similar method to select other elements

```
.ms-cui-tabBody li:nth-child(5)  .ms-cui-row:nth-child(2){display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using id in the selector we can hide the button as follows,

jQuery("Ribbon.Documents.Copies.ManageCopies-Medium").hide();

jQuery("Ribbon.Documents.Copies.SendTo-Medium").hide();

jQuery("Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer-Medium").hide();